# Avoid duplicating template arguments in declaration of template partial specialization of derived class

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, derived-class, partial-specialization

I basically wanted to do partial specialization of functions (on non-type template parameters). Because partial specialization of functions is not allowed in C++ for some reason, I decided to put the functions in a struct that I can then partially specialize. The wrap-functions-in-a-class approach turns out to be otherwise convenient, too, because I have multiple functions that I wanted to specialize, but they can all live in the same struct.

Then I decided to put shared stuff in a base class. So I have code like this:

```
template<int size, typename A, typename B, typename C>
struct Base {
protected:

    // Some types and static functions go here.
};

template<int size, typename A, typename B, typename C>
struct Deri final: protected Base<size, A, B, C> {
    // ...
};

template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
struct Deri<1, A, B, C> final: protected Base<1, A, B, C> {
    // ...
};

// 2 to 8 ...

template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
struct Deri<9, A, B, C> final: protected Base<9, A, B, C> {
    // ...
};

template<int size, typename A, typename B, typename C>
/* function return type */ some_func_name(/* function parameters */) {
    return Deri<size, A, B, C>::some_member(/* ... */);
}

template<int size, typename A, typename B, typename C>
/* function return type */ some_other_func_name(/* function parameters */) {
    return Deri<size, A, B, C>::some_other_member(/* ... */);
}
```

The part in my code that I have a problem with is the lines like this one:

```
struct Deri<1, A, B, C> final: protected Base<1, A, B, C> {
```

To be specific it bothers me that I have to duplicate `<1, A, B, C>`.

How to do this in a nicer way?

Comment: You can use macro, and I don't think there is a simple and nice solution if you *really* need to specialize 9 classes.

Comment: Hmm, true. But I think using a macro would be the greater evil in this case; I'm not *that* bothered by the code duplication.

Comment: What are you doing different with 1 through 9?  Are you really creating utterly different and unrelated code there based on the value of that integer?  If not, there are plenty of ways to make your work cleaner.  Second, instead of specializing override.  Use a trampoline and integral constant types.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont First question: for different values of the size template parameter, the code is mathematically related, but it's not something I can use to unify the implementations in C++. Basically the size parameter determines (among other things) the number of loops in the implementation, and it's not possible to programmatically generate loops within C++.

Comment: @user23 Naw, that is possible.  Arcane, but you can make C++ generate an n-deep recursive loop based off a compile time integer.  (It won't look like you might think, but...)  I could see that being more obtuse than you'd want, admittedly.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Could you point me to a reference or SO question on this technique that you refer to? In case it makes a difference, the loops are all nested, so they look like this: `for (something) { ... for (something) { something; } ... }`.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont regarding using trampolines, do I understand correctly that using a trampoline would probably have a run-time cost?

Comment: in C++!&m `if constexpr` might avoid the need of specialization.

Comment: That's true, I wouldn't even need to do partial specialization if I branched on size, however I think the current approach is nicer. Not sure about it yet, though.

Comment: Ended up going with Jarod's solution.

Comment: No, compilers are good at inlining trampolines.  Generating nested for loops is tricky, but not.much different in structure than a constexpr naive fib calculator.